# Is there any valid Theory that Categorizes statements to levels of their truthfulness?

Tags: logic, epistemology, truth, reason

Is there any valid Theory that Categorizes statements to levels of their truthfulness? and if you consider this theory to be true what is the reasoning behind it?

Because if we look we find that absolute certainty is nearly impossible we don't really know and I think this is the highest category of truth soo I want to know if we can by this approach categorize the propositions by their level of truthfulness

Comment: "Truthiness" is not a real word. It was made up by a comedian because it sounds funny. The word you are looking for is "truthfulness".

Comment: @DavidGudeman thank you i fixed it now can you help me with the theory for levels of truthfulness?

Comment: It's not clear what you want, but I'd suggest looking up "fuzzy logic" to see if that's what you are looking for.

Comment: @DavidGudeman The OED disagree with you. There's an [entry for truthy](https://www.oed.com/dictionary/truthy_adj?tl=true). Truthy simply means appearing to be true. It describes something that appears to be true or feels like it should be true, but may not necessarily be based on objective evidence or facts. It is often associated with subjective or emotional reasoning rather than logical or empirical support.

Comment: For the record, 'real word' is weasel language. When words come into popular existence, they are simply [neologisms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neologism). That doesn't make them 'fake words'.

Comment: There are systems for indicating degree of truth used by [fact checkers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fact-checking). I'm not sure that the systems employed in the industry rise to the level of philosophical theory. Part of the problem is that there are [multiple theories of truth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_Kirkham#Philosophical_work). Part of the problem is that there are multiple [theories of semantics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantics). Part of the problem is that truth isn't easy to quantify, though fuzzy logic can be used.

Comment: @JD, So, some dictionary has acknowledged the existence of a joke word made up by a comedian on a fake news show. There is a paywall for the definition, but if the definition doesn't say that is intended, not as a serious description of truth, but as a term of mockery against people who are concerned with the truth, then the definition is incomplete..

Comment: @DavidGudeman You're of course free and able to dismiss the OED as "some dictionary", although their authority in English is quite established. It's a neologism because it is used, and it is used because it is useful. And Colbert didn't actually invent the word. Take a look at [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=truthy&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3). The English language is beyond any one person's subjective tastes as accounted for by the data you've been provided. You're free to reject the reasoning as you see fit, of course.

Answer (score 3):

First, thank you for an interesting question! Here is what I think is going on.

We humans have two distinct mental faculties, let's call them System 1 and System 2. They share the same purpose: to process our experiences and decide what to do next. However, the way they work is nothing alike.

System 2 deals with absolutes: with knowledge and truth. It is either-or, it either knows something, or it doesn't. What it knows it considers true. What contradicts its knowledge it considers false. There is no gray area in between.

System 1, on the other hand, is a raw neural network that deals with statistics and probabilities. Paraphrasing Jesus, there is no truth in it. While System 2 processes experience into knowledge, System 1 keeps integrating it into its statistical models -- something we consciously recognize as feelings, as intuition.<sup>1</sup>

Often it easy to confuse the two. A classic example is one's idea of a chair. It's not knowledge, it's a statistical model (and that's why it's impossible to *explain* what a chair is). However, we are so *confident* in our ability to recognize a chair when we see one, it feels like knowledge. We might be much less certain in other circumstances, and that's where System 1's has an edge over System 2 -- the former can deal with uncertainty, the latter cannot.

Similarly, System 1 (who actually is in charge) forms ideas of how confident it is in System 2's knowledge (and, in indeed, in its capacity to know). Which brings us to your question -- is there such thing as different levels of truthfulness? While I don't think that a statement can be somewhat true (unless "somewhat" means partially), I do believe that there is always a gray continuum -- our feeling of how *confident* we are in that statement being true.

Thanks for reading this far. This is a complex topic, and I hope this answer will give you some food for thought.

<sup>1</sup> Notably, English philosopher John Locke also thought that our mind produces two distinct kinds of ideas -- complex and simple ideas respectively. Immanuel Kant was making similar distinction between concepts and intuitions. As we keep rediscovering the same concepts, we often come up with different words to describe them.

Comment: It seems that you just present some personal thoughts, without giving any references or arguments. Your two claims about Locke and Kant are rather unprecise - and at least misleading.

Comment: @JoWehler what do you think can be a valid theory Jo? I will really appreciate your opinion since you gave me really good arguments in my solution to radical skepticism question

Answer (score 2):

I have not seen any proposal for such theory. In particular, any proposal of such theory had to deal with the question how to categorize the theory itself.

But scientific progress is possible and is actually achieved by recognizing errors in existing theories. And improving or even dismissing the theory if the errors are too severe: geocentric model, existence of ether, élan vital, phlogiston …

The insight to follow a wrong approach can be the stimulus to look around for alternatives.
By eliminating or improving erroneous theories we develop better theories. The principle is sometimes phrased

> We err upwords (Gerhard Vollmer).